# Strange issue serializing array of DateTime and back

Tags: c#, datetime, serialization, deserialization

I am experiencing a strange issue when serializing a large array of `DateTime` (each timestamp is of Kind UTC). I proceeded with the following steps:

- convert each `DateTime` to type `long` via `DateTime.ToBinary()`
- convert `long[]` to `byte[]` via Buffer.BlockCopy
- write the byte array to a file stream
- read in the byte array via file stream
- convert `byte[]` to `long[]` via Buffer.BlockCopy
- convert each `long` back to DateTime via `DateTime.FromBinary(long)`

The issue is that the DateTimes are **not** matching between the original array and the final array. In fact some of the time stamps show as year 2059 or so when the original array strictly contained time stamps of the past.

I run the entire procedure on my local machine in Windows 10 hence there should be no time zone issues nor issues of endianess. Can someone help?

This is how I convert time stamps of type `DateTime` to `long[]`:

```
var dataCollection = new DataCollection(header.DataProviderId, DateTimeKind.Utc, header.Symbol, header.QuoteType, header.Compression)
        {
            TimeStamps = quotes.Select(x => x.TimeStamp.ToBinary()).ToArray(),
            Bid = quotes.Select(x => x.Bid).ToArray(),
            Ask = quotes.Select(x => x.Ask).ToArray()
        };
```

Here are the conversions between `long[]` -> `byte[]` and back:

```
public static byte[] SerializeBlockCopy<T>(Array sourceArray, long sourceStartIndex, long numberItemsToSerialize)
    {
        var targetArraySize = numberItemsToSerialize * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        var targetArray = new byte[targetArraySize];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(sourceArray, (int)sourceStartIndex, targetArray, 0, (int)targetArraySize);
        return targetArray;
    }

    public static T[] DeserializeBlockCopy<T>(byte[] sourceArray)
    {
        var targetArraySize = sourceArray.Length / Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        var targetArray = new T[targetArraySize];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(sourceArray, 0, targetArray,0, sourceArray.Length);
        return targetArray;
    }
```

Comment: Sounds strange, do you have some example code?

Comment: @Oliver, let me add some code snippets but I can't post the entire library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't spot any errors. Here is an example program I tested with your methods and they worked as expected:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var random = new Random();
    var sourceDates = Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
        .Select(i => DateTime.UtcNow.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(random.Next(-1000, 1000))))
        .ToList();

    var values = sourceDates.Select(date => date.ToBinary()).ToArray();
    var asBytes = SerializeBlockCopy(values, 0, values.Length);
    var filename = Path.GetTempFileName();
    WriteToFile(asBytes, filename);

    var bytesFromFile = ReadFromFile(filename);
    var back = DeserializeBlockCopy<long>(bytesFromFile);
    File.Delete(filename);
    var destinationValues = back.Select(value => DateTime.FromBinary(value)).ToList();
    var pairs = sourceDates.Zip(destinationValues, (s, d) => (s, d));

    foreach (var pair in pairs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{pair.s} -> {pair.d}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Both are equal: {sourceDates.SequenceEqual(destinationValues)}");
}

public static void WriteToFile(byte[] source, string filename)
{
    using (var writer = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        writer.Write(source, 0, source.Length);
    }
}

public static byte[] ReadFromFile(string filename)
{
    return File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
}
```

For a slight improvement you could change the signature of your serialize method to:

```
public static byte[] SerializeBlockCopy<T>(T[] sourceArray, long sourceStartIndex, long numberItemsToSerialize)
```

Then you don't need to provide the generic argument, cause type inference jumps in, but that wouldn't explain your error.

Comment: I tried that already and just serializing and deserializing on the fly works fine. But somehow when it goes to disk and back something strange is going on.

Comment: Maybe you should check that code and make a byte comparison of the written and read bytes like in the example above. If you add theses methods to the above example you could quite easily also check the input and output of those methods too.

Comment: Just added some code to write to and read from a file on disk and no error occurs.

Comment: I noticed that there are no errors on my side either when reading the entire file. So, I guess the error must be residing in my routine to find a start and end time stamp on file and only reading that chunk. Thank you for your help, I could reduce the potential error to the finding of a time stamp directly in the random access binary file.

Comment: Found a nasty bug in the Buffer.BlockCopy method. Even the offsets have to be expressed in byte-length not element length when dealing with other primitives in the source array.